# Using AngularJS datetimepicker, form not submitting correct time

Tags: angularjs, forms, date, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker in my `Angular` / `Node` application.

I render a form like this (I cannot use only ajax for this so I need to post it the traditional way)

**index.jade**

```
form(action='/api/save' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group.m-top-15
        datetimepicker(min-date="minDate" minute-step="minuteStep" ng-model="activationDate" show-meridian="false" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" show-spinners="true")
        input(type='hidden' name='activationDate' ng-value='activationDate')
        input(type='submit')
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.toggleMinDate = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};

$scope.toggleMinDate();

$scope.minuteStep = 15;
```

When I select a date and render the `$scope.activationDate` in the browser it is displayed as `"2015-10-23T06:15:00.000Z"`

But in the request payload it is displayed as `Fri Oct 23 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Västeuropa, sommartid)` (Note the time is not beeing submitted)

In my `MongoDB` the date is saved as `ISODate("2015-10-22T22:00:00Z")`

Why is time not working? Let me know if you need to see some more code. Thank's!

Comment: are you converting date before sending to mongo?

Comment: Looks like you need to adjust the datetimepicker's "date-format" option.  Try using "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi Sorry I don't know. I am using Express and Mongoose to save the date object from req.body.activationDate.

Comment: while sending data , you need to change the format of date.because if it will be saving the format you have on UI then Mongo will return different date when you will get back it to display.You are not setting hours and minutes. So its taking taking zero (default)

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi I'm submitting the $scope.activationDate with ng-value in my hidden input field. The scope has correct time (as it's working in the browser). I cannot understand why it's converting the scopes time to zero as soon as I submit the form...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use filters while displaying date

```
{{activationDate| date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply, however my problem is not related to display. It displays correctly in the browser, including time but as soon as I submit the form it clears time settings. I have tried to edit the "date-format" option with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue using a different datetimepicker

https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker

Now I can successfully post the date and time.

Comment: Right, that plugin wasn't  sending complete date and your hours were set to 0